# Looking to create buttons automatically from a JSON file

Tags: json, vue.js

I'm trying to create buttons inside a CSS grid but i don't know how many buttons i'm expecting from a JSON file (could be 5 could be 55).

How can i automatically create this list of buttons by parsing this JSON file ?

```
"badges": {
  "first" : "first badge",
  "second" : "second badge",
  "third" : "third badge",
  "fourth" : "fourth badge",
  "fifth" : "fifth badge"
}
```

help?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve it with a single line of code by using [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) method.

**Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    badges: {
      first : "first badge",
      second : "second badge",
      third : "third badge",
      fourth : "fourth badge",
      fifth : "fifth badge"
        },
    buttons: []
  },
  mounted() {
    this.buttons = Object.values(this.badges);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button v-for="(btn, index) in buttons" :key="index">
    {{ btn }}
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: The page i'm working on isn't App.vue, it's MainPage.vue inside its own directory, and the JSON file is in a seperate file in its own tree of sub directories. I'm very new to VueJS and even though front end development isn't new to me this language is. It isn't exactly easy i'm sorry.

Comment: Is this will not work for you ?